# cocos2d-x v3.8のカスタムシェーダーで、あとからsetUniformLocationで変更を反映する

Tags: cocos2d-x, opengl-es, opengl

cocos2d-x v3.8でカスタムシェーダーを使おうとしています。

ボタンを押してmenuCallbackが呼ばれるたびに、_spriteが明るくなっていって
最終的に真っ白に輝くようにしたいのですが、
エラーが出てスプライトが明るくならず、ずっと黒いままです。

起動直後に出るエラーメッセージ
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

ボタンを押したときに出るメッセージ
OpenGL error 0x0502 in /Users/username/shadertest/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCFrameBuffer.cpp applyFBO 444

どうすれば明るさを変えられるようになるでしょうか。

HelloWorld.cpp

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    /*中略*/

    _sprite = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("RRGPlayer/walk/south/0001.png");
    _sprite->setPosition(visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x,
                       visibleSize.height / 2 + origin.y);
    addChild(_sprite, 10);

    _glProgram = GLProgram::createWithFilenames("myshader.vsh", "myshader.fsh");
    CC_SAFE_RETAIN(_glProgram);
    _glProgram->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_POSITION, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION);
    _glProgram->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_COLOR, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_COLOR);
    _glProgram->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEX_COORD, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORDS);
    _glProgram->link();
    menuCallback(nullptr);
    _sprite->setGLProgram(_glProgram);

    return true;
}


void HelloWorld::menuCallback(Ref* pSender)
{
    static float brightness = 0.0f;
    _glProgram->setUniformLocationWith1f(_glProgram->getUniformLocationForName("u_brightness"), brightness);
    _glProgram->updateUniforms();

    brightness += .1f;
    if (brightness > 2) {
        brightness = 0;
    }
}
```

myshader.fsh

```
varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform float u_brightness;

void main()
{
    vec4 v_orColor = v_fragmentColor * texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_orColor.r * u_brightness,
                        v_orColor.g * u_brightness,
                        v_orColor.b * u_brightness,
                        v_orColor.a);
}
```

myshader.vsh

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
attribute vec4 a_color;

varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = CC_PMatrix * a_position;
    v_fragmentColor = a_color;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GLProgramStateを使ってできました。

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    /*中略*/

    _sprite = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("RRGPlayer/walk/south/0001.png");
    _sprite->setPosition(visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x,
                       visibleSize.height / 2 + origin.y);
    addChild(_sprite, 10);

    GLProgram* glProgram = GLProgram::createWithFilenames("myshader.vsh", "myshader.fsh");
    GLProgramState* state = GLProgramState::getOrCreateWithGLProgram(glProgram);
    _sprite->setGLProgramState(state);

    return true;
}


void HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback(Ref* pSender)
{
    static float brightness = 0.0f;
    GLProgramState* state = _sprite->getGLProgramState();
    state->setUniformFloat("u_brightness", brightness);

    brightness += .1f;
    if (brightness > 2) {
        brightness = 0;
    }
}
```